# DTED data in Postgis databse served using geoserver and WCS

Tags: geoserver

I have loaded some DTED data into a Postgis database. I am wondering how to connect this data to geoserver's WCS server. I have it working with the GDAL plugins by referencing the dted file, but I cannot figure out how to use it to access the data in the postgis database. Is this possible? Can anyone give me some idea of how to do this. Thanks, David

Comment: I just found [this](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/postgis.html#using-jndi)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This works for vector layers, but I was wondering about DTED layers. I can connect them using the DTED GDAL plugin when pointing to a file, but not when pointing to a table in a database.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that you are trying to connect a raster layer. sorry. maybe  [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/181575)  can be useful